# wait_fences: failed to receive reply: 10004003 and navigationcontrollers in tabs

Tags: ios, ipad, wait-fences

I'm having a heck of a time with the

```
 infamous wait_fences: failed to receive reply: 10004003
```

console message on an iPad app. I've searched Stack Overflow in vain for a solution, but most answers seem to be talking about textfields and the like.

My app has four tabs. Within each tab is a navigationcontroller. At launch, each tab has a view that displays a grid. (MMGridView by René Sprotte). When you click the grid, it displays a new grid by pushing onto the stack the usual way:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:c animated:YES];
```

My problem: on the first view of a particular tab, I can rotate all night and day and the view rotates nicely. But, once I've pushed another one onto the stack, I get the dreaded wait_fences console error upon rotation. And there is a big pause. Then it rotates. If I do this a couple more times to the same grid, I can cause it to crash.

Clearly I'm missing something obvious. What gives? How can I fix this?

Comment: check you don't have some very large frame or image inside your grid (much larger than the screen). This is often a reason of the "wait_fences" issue

Comment: I looked, but I couldn't find any extraordinarily large frames nor images in the view. The weird thing is that this new view is more or a less a direct copy of the view that was used to push this new view onto the stack. That first view (top view) doesn't exhibit this problem at at all.

Comment: Well, it looks like I was running into this wait_fences problem for two reasons. One, you were correct, in one of my views, I do have large images. But in another view, the problem was that I was setting a fetchedResultsController to nil. 

__fetchedResultsController = nil;

I removed that line of code and the fences stopped. The large images issue is still to be solved, but I'm much closer. Thanks for the helpful advice!